# Error: Facebook cannot download due to an error (923)

Tags: google-play-store

I am using my browser to access my Facebook account since I cannot access it through Facebook app. What I did was to uninstall the app and reinstall it. However, when I was trying to reinstall the Facebook app, I was receiving an error message saying

> Facebook cannot download due to an error (923).

Why is it so?

Comment: have you tried our [tag:google-play-store] tag wiki? It lists common solutions to google play store issues.

Comment: Do you see the error specifically for Facebook app installation or for any app installation? Are you using Google Play Store to download the app? If that's the case, see [What does error 923 when downloading apps from Google Play Store mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58614)

Comment: I am experiencing the same error to any app I am trying to download using Google Play Store. So, I followed the basic troubleshooting I read about error 923. I was able to download successfully  the facebook app, however, I cannot open the app. It suddenly closes after a few minutes of white screen then a pop-up option appears whether to close the app or wait til it loads up. Even if I'll tap the wait button, it will still close.

Comment: Possibly it's a duplicate, however, does error 923  affects opening the app after successfully downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough internal memory for the app to downloaded?! the facebook app is around 43mb in size...but on installing it consumes more than that!! But by android and Play Store conventions you need at least a minimum of 150-200mb free to be able to install an app apart from the size of the app you wish to install...so if you need to install an app which is around 50mb, you need to make sure that there is atleast 250mb of free internal storage(would be much more in case of the facebook app...coz on installing it takes up around 150mb)
In case you have enough memory...move the app to external memory once installed and then open the app